# Will my roof rot if I put steel over wet framing?

Tags: ceiling, roofing, leaks, metal-roof

My mother's roof has been leaking for over 3 years now. Ceilings falling in in some rooms and leaks in most. She paid someone to put the roof on and he brought the all metal, put on 10 feet of roof and never came back. So now the question is... if I put the roof on myself will it simply rot everything  underneath considering there's so much moisture? My thought was to put on the roof and knock out the ceiling in the worst rooms and put in space heaters, fans, dehumidifiers, etc and then put new ceilings in once it's dried out. Would this be an option that would work (A.K.A save the the house/make it livable till it can be fixed properly by a professional)?

Comment: What sort of climate is this in?  Is there likely to be weeks (at least) of dry weather?  What is the humidity like?

Comment: This question [has been asked](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/54507/cody-pace?tab=questions) in more or less the same fashion by this user twice before. They've also been abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

First, stop the leaking. Use tarps or whatever. Next, I’d try to dry the roof structure out before installing the metal roofing. (Yes, the roof structure should be dry before installing the roofing.) I’d also check for mold, (as you say the roof has been leaking for 3 years). It may not be safe to stay in the house and continue breathing that air.

Comment: If there is mold what would be the best way to get rid of it?

Comment: @CodyPace Abating (removing) mold is dangerous. Scraping mold off any material will cause it to fly like dust. You’ll need special respirators, special bags to dispose of it, special fans to contain it in your house so it doesn’t float out the windows and around the neighborhood. I think you’ll need an abatement contractor, but first I’d get it tested so you know the extent, type, etc.

Comment: A simple hydrogen peroxide solution at 3%  will destroy surface mold if present but nothing will stop deep spores, I live in the Pacific north west and stopping the leak is the first priority, then removing the moisture, waste time on trying temporary methods with a limited budget and then a big wind takes the tarp off and you are at square one or trying to do the job a year later oops the cheap tarp just blew off in a winter storm, wait till it is dry no way in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a comment)

How many layers of shingles or type of shingles are on the current roof?

Your mom paid someone; was that person licensed? This needs to be addressed. I don't like it when anyone gets ripped off but get especially upset when it is an elderly person.

Limited info provided on the existing roof:

- Is there is only 1 or 2 layers of 3 tab roofing?
- Was the original guy just overlaying the metal roofing?  If so continue doing that.
- If there are more than 2 layers, they need to be removed including where the first 10' of metal was installed and the roofing under that.

The big thing is to stop the leaks first. Next you need to get some fans to move the air around and from the sound.

If the condition of the property several dehumidifiers. The next part is a judgment call after putting the new roof on, is the sheet rock sagging and the insulation above saturated? Then it should all be removed, however I understand if she is on a fixed budget it may be best to just remove the insulation for now so the sheetrock can dry and be replaced as funds are available.

You don't want the ceiling open when winter or cold weather is in your area or she won't be able to heat the home. I suggest removing the insulation as it as good as a sponge and will hold water for a very long time so removal will help reduce moisture levels quickly. I have additional comments and ideas but without additional information it may not be helpful.

Comment: This would have been okay to add as (many) comments to the OP.